# RouteReuseStrategy and Lazy loading in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have multiple modules in which they are lazy loaded and i am trying to use the RouteReuseStrategy.

Currently i am able to get the functionality that i want and reusing routes except in on situation. I have a list that is being displayed on the homepage and when i try to click on a list item i get this error: 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined**

While debugging i noticed that after the page i am supposed to see loads it then goes to 'shouldDetach' which returns true and then removes the page content and displays the above error.

My question is in what order do the methods in the CustomReuseStrategy execute so i can prevent it from being removed after it loads.

This is my class:

```
export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

public handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

constructor() {}

public calcKey(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    let next = route;
    while (next.firstChild) {
        next = next.firstChild;
    }
    const segments: string[] = [];
    while (next) {
        segments.push(next.url.join("/"));
        next = next.parent;
    }
    let url = segments.reverse().join("/");
    return url;
}
/**
 * Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be detached to be reused later.
 */
public shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldDetach', route);
    return true;
}
/**
* Stores the detached route.
*/
public store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:store', route, handle);
    this.handlers[this.calcKey(route)] = handle;
}
/**
* Determines if this route (and its subtree) should be reattached.
*/
public shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldAttach', route);
    return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[this.calcKey(route)];
}
/**
 * Retrieves the previously stored route.
 */
public retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:retrieve', route);
    if (!route.routeConfig) {
        return null;
    }
    return this.handlers[this.calcKey(route)]; 

}
/**
* Determines if a route should be reused.
*/
public shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldReuseRoute', future, curr);
    return this.calcKey(curr) === this.calcKey(future);
}
}
```

Would really appreciate help on this.